# Bound related to Schwartz space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

If $u \in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then is there an integer $m \ge 0$ and $C>0$ such that for all $\phi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$,$$|u(\phi)| \le C\|\phi\|_m,$$where$$\|\phi\|_m = \sum_{|\alpha| + |\beta| \le m} \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} |x^\alpha \partial_x^\beta \phi|?$$

Comment: The topology in $\mathcal{S}$ is given by the countable family of seminorms $\sup \lvert x^\alpha \partial^\beta_x \phi \rvert$. Thus this is just continuity of $u$.

Comment: What are $||$ and $\|\|_m$?

Answer (score 0):

We suppose the choice $m = j$, $C = j$ does not work for any $j$ and derive a contradiction. There thus exist Schwartz functions $\phi_j$ such that $|u(\phi_j)| > j\|\phi_j\|_j$, so if we define$$\psi_j = {1\over{j\|\phi_j\|_j}}\phi_j,$$it is clear that $|u(\psi_j)| > 1$ while $\|\psi_j\|_j = 1/j$. To show that $\psi_j \to 0$ in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, it suffices to show that the norm$$\|\psi_j\| = d(\psi_j, 0) = \sum_{N = 0}^\infty 2^{-N} \tilde{d}_N(\psi_j, 0)$$converges to zero as $j \to \infty$. But this is straightforward, for given any $k > j$, we have$$\|\psi_k\|_j \le \|\psi_k\|_k = {1\over k} \to 0$$as $k \to 0$. Hence, given any $\epsilon > 0$, we may choose some large $N_0 > 0$ such that$$\sum_{N = N_0}^\infty 2^{-N} < {\epsilon\over2},$$and then choose $k$ so large that $2/k < \epsilon/2$. Then since $\tilde{d}_N(\psi, 0) \le 1$ for all $N$ by definition, we have\begin{align*} \|\psi_k\| & = d(\psi_k, 0) = \sum_{N = 0}^{N_0} 2^{-N} \tilde{d}_N(\psi_k, 0) + \sum_{N = N_0}^\infty 2^{-N} \tilde{d}_N(\psi_k, 0) \\ & \le \sum_{N = 0}^{N_0} 2^{-N}\left({1\over k}\right) + \sum_{N = N_0}^\infty 2^{-N} \le {\epsilon\over2} + {\epsilon\over2} = \epsilon,\end{align*}proving the claim. Hence, $\psi_k \to 0$ in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, which is a contradiction because $u$ is continuous on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $u(\psi_k) > 1$. This contradiction proves that the choice $m = j$, $C = j$ satisfies$$|u(\phi)| \le C\|\phi\|_m$$for all $\phi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and some $j$, and so we are done.